# In LODASH, What is the best way to assert the existence of a key inside an object or array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, frontend, lodash

In my project I can receive 2 different kinds of response:

```
var data ={
  'ADULT':{},
  'bounds':[],
  'checkInEligible':true,
  'departureDate':'2016-07-15',
  'id':'car'
}
```

or I can get also the response:

```
var data = {
  ADULT:{
    'confirmationNumber':'29YNK',
    'checkInEligible':true
  },
  bounds:[],
  departureDate:"2016-07-15",`enter code here`
  id:"air"
}
```

I need to assert with some lodash method that the key 'checkInEligible' exist at some level into the response.

I've tried with the method .some, but seems to work fine only with arrays and only for root level, because return true only when the object os at a root level.

I've tried this:

```
isCheckInEligible: function () {
    return _.some(data, function (value, key) {
        return key === 'checkInEligible' && value
    });
}
```

Or this:

```
isCheckInEligible: function () {
    return _.some(data, 'checkInEligible');
}
```

Can somebody help me with this lodash method or any other lodash method?
But I HAVE TO use lodash.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `data.checkInEligible || data.ADULT.checkInEligible`? You above `isCheckInEligible`'s `&& value` makes it seem you aren't only interested in the key's existence but also its value.

Comment: The problem is that I can have different paths, not only these two. I need to check trough all over the object. Thank YOU!!

Comment: Then your question is unclear. You said "I can receive 2 different kinds of response" and there are only two possible paths as far as I can see - `data.checkInEligible` and `data.ADULT.checkInEligible`. What other paths do you need to account for? E.g. `data.CHILD.checkInEligible`?

Comment: you're right I have 2 different so far but I realize I can get different more permutation on thi sresponse. So I Want to know if there's a lodash mathod that can give me the response no matter where the key is?

Once again thank you!

Comment: Are you only interested in the key's existence or also its value? (see my first comment) Also - array's can't have keys ("... existence of a key inside an object or array?")

Comment: Leonardo, can you edit the question to reflect the above comments?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using `_.has` ?

```
isCheckInEligible: () => {
    return _.has(data, 'checkInEligible') || _.has(data, 'ADULT.checkInEligible');
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can have different paths, not only these two. I need to check trough all over the object.

Thank YOU!!

Comment: Leonardo, again, can you give a few more examples of what your data could look like ...

Comment: @LeonardoUribe You should specify that in the question (you said you have two types of responses) - and which level deep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lodash#some`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) to traverse both objects and arrays to check if a certain key exists in any level. Just make sure to name the `lodash#some` iteratee to recursively traverse the object/array.

```
function hasKeyDeep(object, key) {
  return _.has(object, key) || _.isObject(object) &&
    _.some(object, _.partial(hasKeyDeep, _, key));
}
```

```js
function hasKeyDeep(object, key) {
  return _.has(object, key) || _.isObject(object) &&
    _.some(object, _.partial(hasKeyDeep, _, key));
}

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  'ADULT':{},
  'bounds':[],
  'checkInEligible':true,
  'departureDate':'2016-07-15',
  'id':'car'
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  'ADULT':{},
  'bounds':[],
  'departureDate':'2016-07-15',
  'id':'car'
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  ADULT:{
    'confirmationNumber':'29YNK',
    'checkInEligible':true
  },
  bounds:[],
  departureDate:"2016-07-15",
  id:"air"
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  ADULT:{
    'confirmationNumber':'29YNK'
  },
  bounds:[],
  departureDate:"2016-07-15",
  id:"air"
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  bounds:[{
    'checkInEligible': true,
    'otherValue': 'another value'
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  bounds:[{
    'otherValue': 'another value'
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  a: [{
      b: [{
        c: [{
          d: [{
            'checkInEligible': true
          }]
        }]
      }]
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  a: [{
      b: [{
        c: [{
          d: [{
            'anotherKey': true
          }]
        }]
      }]
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false
```

```css
body > div { top: 0; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another approach is to use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) in a stringified object using [`JSON#stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
function hasKeyDeep(object, key) {
  return new RegExp('[{,]"' + key + '":')
    .test(JSON.stringify(object));
}
```

```js
function hasKeyDeep(object, key) {
  return new RegExp('[{,]"' + key + '":')
    .test(JSON.stringify(object));
}

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  'ADULT':{},
  'bounds':[],
  'checkInEligible':true,
  'departureDate':'2016-07-15',
  'id':'car'
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  'ADULT':{},
  'bounds':[],
  'departureDate':'2016-07-15',
  'id':'car'
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  ADULT:{
    'confirmationNumber':'29YNK',
    'checkInEligible':true
  },
  bounds:[],
  departureDate:"2016-07-15",
  id:"air"
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  ADULT:{
    'confirmationNumber':'29YNK'
  },
  bounds:[],
  departureDate:"2016-07-15",
  id:"air"
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  bounds:[{
    'checkInEligible': true,
    'otherValue': 'another value'
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  bounds:[{
    'otherValue': 'another value'
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  a: [{
      b: [{
        c: [{
          d: [{
            'checkInEligible': true
          }]
        }]
      }]
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => true

console.log(hasKeyDeep({
  a: [{
      b: [{
        c: [{
          d: [{
            'anotherKey': true
          }]
        }]
      }]
  }]
}, 'checkInEligible')); // => false
```

```css
body > div { top: 0; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive check down the object `has-a` tree to see if any contained object has the attribute (object property) that you're looking for.

```js
function nestedHas(object, attrib) {
  if (_.has(object, attrib)) {
    return true;
  }
  for (let key in _.pickBy(object, _.isObject)) {
    if (nestedHas(object[key], attrib)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note:  This doesn't check for the key in arrays, just in objects.

Comment: Also, if this is what you are looking for, you might want to rephrase your question a bit, as well as expand the examples you're giving.